# Assign a single title attribute across multiple columns of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table wherein adjacent `<th>` and `<td>` elements need the same `title` attribute. (That is, the same tool-tip when a user hovers over them.) The table is currently made in this fashion:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th title="Zero-based index.">i:</th>
        <td title="Zero-based index.">15</td>
        <th title="Velocity in MPH.">v:</th>
        <td title="Velocity in MPH.">15.45 NE</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

*Note that each row has a different arrangement of columns, and the `table` setup is used because the data are tabular and to cheaply enforce alignment.*

My question is, can this be done without including the text `"Zero-based index."` and `"Velocity in MPG."` multiple times? Enclosing the `td` and `th` elements in a `span` is not allowed (won't validate or work in browsers).

Comment: You can span the titles across multiple columns by using C# is what I know.

Comment: Probably have to loop through with JS to do that.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible in plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, this should do it:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.each($('td'), function () {
            $(this).attr('title', ($(this).prev('th').attr('title')));
        });
    });
```

It sets each td (in this case, for the whole document) to the previous th's title.

Comment: This would probably do, but I marked the question as HTML rather than JavaScript hoping to find a "clean" HTML or CSS-only way to make the layout. Thanks for your input, none-the-less.

Comment: Do the <map> and <area> tags work on tables?  I'm still new to all of this.  That's a much sloppier way if it does work, but just an idea.